# How to type a string as an Object property-key in a typescript Object interface?

Tags: typescript, object-type

I define an interface - the relevant part is here:

```
      actors:{    
        name:{           // options (Object) is specific to each actor type
                        // see documentation at top of each actor
          factory:string,
          url:string,
          options:Object
        }
        //...
      }
```

I implement the interface as follows:

```
      actors:{
        'unitcube':{ 
          factory:'Unitcube',
          url:'../src/app/models/stage/actors/objects/unitcube',
          options:{wireframe:false, 
                color:'red', 
                opacity:0.9, 
                transform:{t:[0.0,2.0,-3.0001],e:[0.0,1.0,0.0],s:[1.0,3.0,1.0]}
          } 
        }
        //...
      }//actors
```

The interface passes tslint, however I receive a tslint/tsc error that the types of the interface and the implementation are different - in particular 'unitcube' and name.

How can I type-specify a list of string-named Objects? (i.e how do I define 'name' in the actors part of the interface?)

Thanks.

Comment: Use an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) as in `{actors: {[name: string]: {factory:string,  url:string,  options:object}}}`, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

```
interface IActors {
   actors: IActorType
}

interface IActorType {
  [name: string]: //so on and so forth
}
```

the interface defined in the question enforces the key to be literally ‘name.’ when implemented with ‘unitcube’ or any other actor’s name, it is evaluated to be not equal to ‘name.’ [name: string] allows this key to be dynamic, so any actor name of type string can be used.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you explain how this works and why it's the best solution to the problem?

Comment: the interface defined in the question enforces the key to be literally ‘name.’ when implemented with ‘unitcube’ or any other actor’s name, it is evaluated to be not equal to ‘name.’ [name: string] allows this key to be dynamic, so any actor name of type string can be used.

Comment: Nice, thanks! I recommend updating the post body to contain that so the robot doesn't flag the post as "low quality".